# extract and format string in text file?

Tags: c#

i have a text file in a format
CODE:8000012016
502 Bad Gateway

### 502 Bad Gateway

#### Host Not Found or connection failed

CODE:8000012146
502 Bad Gateway

### 502 Bad Gateway

#### Host Not Found or connection failed

CODE:8000023700
502 Bad Gateway

### 502 Bad Gateway

#### Host Not Found or connection failed

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
CODE:8001129584
{"event_id":"0D004B66AA326A34","version":"1.6","error":{"system_unavailable":true,"no_tickets":true,"invalid":{"ticketing":true}},"command":"event_authenticate"}

CODE:8001129586
{"event_id":"0D004B66AA326A34","version":"1.6","error":{"system_unavailable":true,"no_tickets":true,"invalid":{"ticketing":true}},"command":"event_authenticate"}
.
.
.
.
.

i have to seperate these two formats and save in new different text files.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: i have to check whether format is first one or last one then i have to save it in a new text file separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, more details please... As I see, you can search for HTML tags.

for example:

```
foreach(LineOfText line in text)
{
    foreach(Word in line)
    {
        if(Word is HtmlTag)
        {
            mark current line as type1;
            put current line in string1;
        }
        else
        {
            mark current line as type2;
            put current line in string2;
        }
    }
}

SaveString(string1);
SaveString(string2);
```

Comment: there are lines between codes

Comment: OK! No problem! if line has html tags, it will be saved

Comment: there are lines between code, in firs format length between code to code is 5 and in second it is 4, now tell me??

Comment: I'm confused! are you trying to say: "format1 and format2 are blended together"  ?

Comment: format 1 means in which html tags exist and the other written in the end of body in question

Comment: ok! You your self said that: format1 is... and format2 is... Why didn't you convert your idea to code?!

Comment: what should i do ?
i get streaming of symbols, 100 symbols in 1 second and every symbol has to be checked from database which takes 10 symbols in 1 second and i m loosing 90 in 1 second.
any suggestion?